# time complexity for a loop

Tags: python, complexity-theory, time-complexity

```
foo = []
i = 1
while i < n:
    foo= foo + ["a"]
    i*=2
```

What is the time complexity of this code?
My thoguht is: 
the while loop does log(n) iteration. For each iteration new list is created.
So, the total time complexity is: O(log^2(n)).

Am I right?

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 4):

The `while` loop iterates log(n) times.

`foo + ["a"]`: Create a new list by copying the original list. According to [Time Complexity - Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), copying a list take O(n).

Time complexity
=> 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + log(n)
=> (log(n) + 1) * log(n) / 2
=> O(log<sup>2</sup>n)

---

I ran a `timeit`: (CPython 2.7.5 64bit, Windows 7)

```
def f(n):
    foo = []
    i = 1
    while i < n:
        foo = foo + ["a"]
        i *= 2

import timeit
for n in range(20):
    print n, timeit.timeit('f({})'.format(2 ** n), 'from __main__ import f')
```

Result:

```
2**0 0.187083903003
2**1 0.455513095565
2**2 0.690063737582
2**3 0.925251130713
2**4 1.16173567555
2**5 1.38232866174
2**6 1.64922777752
2**7 1.89248633685
2**8 2.14087549485
2**9 2.36934465058
2**10 2.62737119511
2**11 2.91843160213
2**12 3.19988987374
2**13 3.43422677799
2**14 3.72119850214
2**15 4.00189195846
2**16 4.31630377356
2**17 4.62789416099
2**18 4.91062905834
2**19 5.24480246883
```

[image]

Comment: -1 This is about time complexity and not about the actual runtime on some test machine. This question can be answered without a computer.

Comment: @Gumbo, editing answer to add about time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

The loop does log(n) iterations.

Now, assuming `foo = foo + ["a"]` copies immediately each element in `foo`to do the concatenation (as opposed to some fancy list-appending) then for each iteration there are also at most `log(n)` copies.

So yes, it is `log(n)*log(n)` = `log^2(n)`

Comment: `+` makes a copy of the two lists into one new one, it does not modify the original instances in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s assume the loop iterates *n* instead of log(*n*) times, then the array copy takes 0+1+2+3+4+…+*n*-2 operations; and with *n*+2 it takes

> 0+1+2+3+4+…+*n* = 1/2·*n*·(*n*+1)

operations. For simplicity, let’s replace *n*+2 by *m*, so *n*+2 = *m*, thus *n* = *m*-2, and

> 1/2·*n*·(*n*+1) = 1/2·(*m*-2)·(*m*-2+1) = 1/2·(*m*-2)·(*m*-1),

which we will use later as

> f(*m*) = 1/2·(*m*-2)·(*m*-1).

Now as the loop’s limit is not *n*+2 but log(*n*), there are not

> f(*n*+2) = 1/2·((*n*+2)-2)·((*n*+2)-1) = 1/2·*n*·(*n*+1) (see divergent series above)

but

> f(log(*n*)) = 1/2·(log(*n*)-2)·(log(*n*)-1)

operations, which is

> 1/2·(log<sup>2</sup>(*n*)-3·log(*n*)+2) ∈ Ο(log<sup>2</sup>(*n*)). ■

Comment: Off topic: how did you manage that? :)   https://twitter.com/Pekkanikolaus/status/408009581227294720/photo/1 (scroll up for context)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Um, so what exactly am I looking at?

Comment: It's a 3-D rendering of the Stack Overflow user base, using reputation: http://ekisto.sq.ro/ your "tower" in that rendering has the anomaly of  having empty space around it (for some mathematical reason) which makes it look like a *Burggraben*. There's nothing special to it except that I found it funny.